# How can columns in SYS schema tables be queried?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS will retrieve the column names in a table.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'EMR_FACILITY'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

However, it appears that there is no SYS schema information in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'sys' AND TABLE_NAME = 'DM_OS_SCHEDULERS'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

How can I query columns in a SYS schema table?

Comment: Maybe the table `[sys].[syscolumns]` is what you are looking for?

Comment: Why do you need to query the metadata for `sys` objects? They're built in to the product and not subject to random changes.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.system_views` holds the system views and can be viewed through their own `sys` views.

All sys views:

```
SELECT 
    SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id), 
    T.* 
FROM 
    sys.system_views T
WHERE
    SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id) = 'sys'
```

A particular sys view columns:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.system_columns AS T 
WHERE T.object_id = (SELECT X.object_id FROM sys.system_views AS X WHERE X.name = 'database_principals')
```

You can work your way to join these to get all columns for all views, and also columns data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more detail (precision, length, if null, etc.) in the system catalog

```
SELECT
     o.name AS [Table_Name]
    ,c.name AS [Column_Name]
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'U' /* -> User Table*/
AND o.name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: But the columns in the `sys` schema won't be found in `sys.columns`.

Comment: syscolumns is an old view that will be deprecated in future versions. you can check it in the MSDN documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscolumns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

`sys.dm_os_schedulers` is a View (not a Table) from `master` DB. You can see its columns as follow:

```
select * from master..syscolumns
where id=Object_Id('master.sys.dm_os_schedulers')
order by colid
```

or

```
select * from master.sys.system_columns
where object_id=Object_Id('master.sys.dm_os_schedulers')
order by column_id
```